# How to install ROS2 on Ubuntu 20.04 with WSL?

Tags: ros, ros2, installation, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running on windows 10 and I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 through the WSL environment. Now I want to install ROS2 on the Ubuntu. Which of the two processes should I follow?

- Install ROS2 for Linux via [Debian packages](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#), since I can use the Ubuntu app download from the WSL, or
- Install ROS2 for [Windows](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html), since my background OS is Windows?

Which is the safest choice to install ROS2 with my setup? Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389059/how-to-install-ros2-on-ubuntu-20.04-with-wsl?/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WSL2 (WSL1 is different) runs Linux inside a VM.

So you should follow the regular Linux-based install tutorial for your version of Linux.

As you mention Ubuntu, that would be the Ubuntu based install tutorials.

> Install ROS2 for Windows, since my background OS is Windows?

*Inside* WSL, there is no Windows. It's all Linux.

You only install ROS 2 using the Windows guides if you intend to write Windows applications using ROS 2. Those don't involve Linux, so no ROS-for-Linux.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-10-21**:
Ok, that makes it clear. First time I work with VM and I was a bit confused. Thanks!